Staging ground link in "Your question is ready for review" banner is broken
The link to learn more about the Staging Ground in the "Your question is ready for review" banner after you ask a question on the stackoverflow.com website is broken.
Immediately after submitting your question for review, this banner along with other text is displayed.

The blue Staging Ground link in the image above is broken. When you click on it, it says Page Not Found. The broken link address that the staging ground link leads to is https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/stackoverflow.com.

My guess is that it should point to https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-staging-ground

Thanks for the report!  The link indeed was just set to new { url = "stackoverflow.com" } ‍♀️
It has been updated to use the learn more url for Askers which is /help/what-is-staging-ground
